# HappyMacUser and ConcernedMacUser

Tags: support, users, user-accounts

These accounts from this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/156921/22781) looks like needs merging:

- [ConcernedMacUser](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/101161/concernedmacuser)
- [HappyMacUser](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/101201/happymacuser)

Is it possible to merge unregistered accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically - anyone can request a merge - use the contact us link at the bottom of any page and link the details you have here.

In specific, moderators can sometimes tell if accounts should be merged and can ask. Most of the time, moderators can't tell and have to rely on the user themselves to indicate a merge is needed.

It's not at all wrong to have many accounts - only when multiple accounts collude to vote or otherwise evade controls or abuse the system is merging and / or corrective actions warranted. Simply having two accounts isn't reason enough to request a merge in most cases.

In this case, it seems intentional and humorous and likely the same person. I'm not going to ask for a merge since the accounts are old and the OP / OP's aren't struggling to use the site.